# Query two tables and get result in customized manner

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables named

1. users
2. messages

Users table structure is,

| id | mobile_no | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9876543210 | 2020-12-30 | 2020-12-30 |
| 2 | 9876543211 | 2020-12-30 | 2020-12-30 |

Messages table structure is,

| id | user_id | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-12-30 | 2020-12-30 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-12-30 | 2020-12-30 |
| 3 | 2 | 2020-12-30 | 2020-12-30 |

I need to know the count of records as like follows,

| user_id | mobile_no | no_of_messages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9876543210 | 2 |
| 2 | 9876543211 | 1 |

How can i achieve this query in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `group by` as follows:

```
select u.id, u.mobile_no, count(*) as msgs
  from users u join messages m
    on m.user_id = u.id
 group by u.id, u.mobile_no
```

Comment: Yeap, I know. That is the practice that I followed in Oracle so used it.

Comment: Also, just `GROUP BY u.id` should be fine on Postgres assuming that `id` is the primary key column of the user table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select 
  user.id, 
  user.mobile_no, 
  count(*) as nos 
from 
  users user 
  join messages message on message.user_id = user.id 
group by 
  user.id, 
  user.mobile_no
```